# Why doesn't bash do brace expansion inside arithmetic expansion?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a question regarding bash syntax. The bash manual, in section 3.5, says this:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion,
> parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command
> substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and
> filename expansion.

Here's the link: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions

Now, these commands do what I expect:

```
$ echo 0 +{1..5}
0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5

$ echo $((0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5))
15
```

So I figured that this command should yield the same result as the second:

```
echo $((0 +{1..5}))
```

However, instead I get this error:

```
bash: 0 +{1..5}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{1..5}")
```

Why is this? Shouldn't it first do the brace expansion inside and then evaluate the arithmetic expansion like in the second command?

Note: I'm not trying to do anything in particular. I'm just trying to understand how bash works.